# distance distributions on a hypersphere?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, real-analysis, discrete-geometry

Fix a real number $0\leq t\leq 1$ and an integer $n>1$. Let 
$\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ denote the unit hypersphere. Define 
$$d_N(n;t):=\max\sum_{i<j}\Vert P_i-P_j\Vert_2^t$$
where the sum is taken over all possible $N$-points 
$P_1,\dots,P_N$ on the sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.

> **Question.** What are the best known estimates (asymptotics) for $d_N(n;t)$? Or, something you can prove.

For example, on the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$,  Fejes Toth (see below) delivered an exact value
$$d_N(2,1)=N\cot\frac{\pi}{2N}.$$

L. Fejes Toth, *On the sum of distances determined by a pointset*, Acta Math. Acad. Sci. Hung. 7 (1956), 397-401.

Comment: @T.Ambederhan can you give reference for Fejes Toth value?

Comment: Reference added.

Comment: do you know analogous result where you replace $\Bbb S^{n-1}$ by an equal volume $n$-torus?